# Align the Columns of the Data-Table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have an `angular-material` Data Table and I want it to align to a certain column left/right.

```
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="col0">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Col0</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.col0}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="col1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Col1 </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.col1}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

What CSS do I need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few googling action I've found the solution in form of a github change request:
[See here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5759)

The short form is like this:

```
.mat-column-col1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

**Just replace the col1 to the column you're gonna need!**

Comment: Remove `display:flex` in new Angular versions (6+). See the link in the answer for more information.